# JAVASCRIPT: Count the number of REGEX results

Tags: javascript, regex, count, find, counter

This is what regex should find `{` `anything in it` `}`, and then I want to count the number of results what the regex found.

So I have a string like this:

`{example1}{example2}{example3}` in this case the count number is `3`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you need the global regex flag (g) to match all occurrences and then simply get the length of the result. the ? makes the .* ungreedy, otherwise it would only once fit the first and the last bracket as regexps are greedy by default.

```
var source = "{example1}{example2}{example3}";
var count = source.match(/\{.*?\}/g).length;
```

Comment: +1 - I misread this as a generic example, he's actually looking for the `{` and `}` :)